# Select rows with same id but different value in another column

Tags: sql

I tried for hours and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+
|ARIDNR|LIEFNR|
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
```

I would like to select the ARIDNR that occurs more than once with the different LIEFNR.

The output should be something like:

```
+------+------+
|ARIDNR|LIEFNR|
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ARIDNR IN (
    SELECT ARIDNR
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ARIDNR
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

The idea is to use the inner query to identify the records which have a `ARIDNR` value that occurs 1+ times in the data, then get all columns from the same table based on that set of values.

Comment: Yes, but he only wants the ones with the different LIEFNR

Comment: Great thanks. It looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for. I will try this in a few minuntes.

Comment: @Segfault I think it's a language issue. He says *different `LIEFNR`*, not that they should actually be different from each other but as one might say *I'd like to see all of the different things you have*.

Comment: The below answer should be the accepted answer for this question

Answer (score 114):

Try this please. I checked it and it's working:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ARIDNR IN (
    SELECT ARIDNR
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY ARIDNR
    HAVING COUNT(distinct LIEFNR) > 1
)
```

Comment: I guess this should be the accepted answer, because you really look for differences in the specific column, not in any column

Comment: This is the required answer

Comment: add `ORDER BY ARIDNR` at the end easy to see duplicates.

Answer (score 12):

Join the same table back to itself.  Use an inner join so that rows that don't match are discarded.  In the joined set, there will be rows that have a matching ARIDNR in another row in the table with a different LIEFNR.  Allow those ARIDNR to appear in the final set.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ARIDNR IN (
    SELECT a.ARIDNR FROM YourTable a
    JOIN YourTable b on b.ARIDNR = a.ARIDNR AND b.LIEFNR <> a.LIEFNR
)
```

Comment: I understand what to do but i got an error that ARIDNR is no clear columne

Comment: Ah, right, check my edited query, you need to specify which table to select from in the sub query.

Comment: Okay, this works. But this selects everything but not my example that i created.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: This table contains all products from actual orders. What i would like to select is if there is the same product(ARIDNR) ordered at different suppliers(LIEFNR) i would like to select only these rows.

Comment: @user3202604, can you explain the problem in more detail?  It works on the data set you provided: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f2f2/1/0

Comment: I fixed the problem with the answer from Yuck. But i bring a better explaination this evening with fiddle. Many thanks till now for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an *old question* yet I find that I also need a solution for this from time to time.  The previous answers are all good and works well, I just personally prefer using [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), for example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ARIDNR INT, LIEFNR varchar(5)) --table variable for loading sample data
INSERT INTO @T (ARIDNR, LIEFNR) VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'A'),(3,'A'),(1,'B'),(2,'B'); --add your sample data to it
WITH duplicates AS --the CTE portion to find the duplicates
(
    SELECT ARIDNR FROM @T GROUP BY ARIDNR HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT t.* FROM @T t --shows results from main table
INNER JOIN duplicates d on t.ARIDNR = d.ARIDNR --where the main table can be joined to the duplicates CTE
```

---

Yields the following results:

> 1|A
>   1|B
>   2|B
>   2|A

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.ARIDNR,A.LIEFNR
from Table A
join Table B
on A.ARIDNR = B.ARIDNR
and A.LIEFNR<> B.LIEFNR
group by A.ARIDNR,A.LIEFNR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE ARIDNR IN
    (SELECT ARIDNR FROM test
     GROUP BY ARIDNR
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY ARIDNR, LIEFNR;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select * from (
 SELECT ARIDNR,LIEFNR,row_number() over 
     (partition by ARIDNR order by ARIDNR) as RowNum) a
where a.RowNum >1
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE item_id=".$item_id;

$query=mysql_query($sql);

while($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

echo   print_r($myrow,1);


}
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.