# select columns' values based on another two values from another column

Tags: sql, subquery, distinct, relation

I have this data set and I need to extract multiple columns values based on on column value.

To elaborate on it, I have a
`rental` table, `inventory` table, `customer` table,
and I want to relate `customer` table to `rental` table by `customer_id` and relate `rental` table to `inventory` table by `inventory_id`, the final purpose is to generate `first_name` and `last_name` of customers of specified `customer_id`.

by

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     SELECT 
     inventory.inventory_id,inventory.store_id,
     rental.customer_id,customer.first_name,customer.last_name
     FROM inventory
     INNER JOIN rental ON inventory.inventory_id=rental.inventory_id
     INNER JOIN customer ON rental.customer_id=customer.customer_id
     WHERE inventory.film_id='25') AS data
;
```

I have achieved the result of

```
inventory_id | store_id | customer_id | first_name | last_name 
--------------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------
          124 |        1 |         265 | Jennie     | Terry
          124 |        1 |         497 | Gilbert    | Sledge
          124 |        1 |         158 | Veronica   | Stone
          125 |        1 |         377 | Howard     | Fortner
          125 |        1 |         163 | Cathy      | Spencer
          125 |        1 |         141 | Debbie     | Reyes
          125 |        1 |         558 | Jimmie     | Eggleston
          126 |        1 |         327 | Larry      | Thrasher
          126 |        1 |         147 | Joanne     | Robertson
          126 |        1 |         225 | Arlene     | Harvey
          126 |        1 |         393 | Philip     | Causey
          126 |        1 |         425 | Francis    | Sikes
          127 |        1 |         336 | Joshua     | Mark
          127 |        1 |         350 | Juan       | Fraley
          128 |        2 |          96 | Diana      | Alexander
          128 |        2 |         273 | Priscilla  | Lowe
          128 |        2 |         163 | Cathy      | Spencer
          129 |        2 |         498 | Gene       | Sanborn
          129 |        2 |         360 | Ralph      | Madrigal
          129 |        2 |         292 | Misty      | Lambert
          129 |        2 |         578 | Willard    | Lumpkin
          129 |        2 |          53 | Heather    | Morris
```

However I want to take a step further to obtain the following table

```
 inventory_id | store_id | customer_id | first_name | last_name 
--------------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------
          124 |        1 |         265 | Jennie     | Terry
          126 |        2 |         265 | Jennie     | Terry
          125 |        1 |         163 | Cathy      | Spencer
          128 |        2 |         163 | Cathy      | Spencer
```

Which is to obtain column values `customer_id`,`first_name` and `last_name` by checking the occurrence of `customer_id` for both `store_id='1'` and `store_id='2'`. I know that I need to do
`COUNT (DISTINCT customer_id)` but I cannot figure out how to apply to achieve it. Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for customers of both stores?  One method uses `exists`:

```
with t as (
      SELECT i.inventory_id, i.store_id,
             r.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
      FROM inventory i JOIN
           rental r
           ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id JOIN
           customer c
           ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
      WHERE i.film_id = 25
     )
select t.*
from t
where t.store_id in ( 1, 2) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.customer_id = t.customer_id and
                    t2.store_id in (1, 2) and
                    t2.store_id <> t.store_id
             );
```

However, if you just want the customers who have purchased in both stores, you can use the simpler query:

```
SELECT r.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM inventory i JOIN
     rental r
     ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id JOIN
     customer c
     ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE i.film_id = 25 AND
      r.store_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY r.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.store_id) = 2;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, your second query will produce the output that I want, however I am grateful to learn the `exist` method. Moreover, from your query and above @fa06 's query, I see the only difference is between the `join` and `inner join`, which is my approach as well, our query however produce `0 results` but yours achieve it, as I searched there is no difference between `join` and `inner join`, but why is there a difference? thank you.

Comment: Ok, I have seen the difference is between the `selection`.in here you didn't `select` on `i.inventory_id`  and `i.store_id` and you didn't `group by` them as well. our query however produce `0 results` but yours achieves it, but why is there a difference between such a `selection` and `group by ` decision? thank you.

Comment: @Sanny . . . Because you are counting *customers* in the second query, so you cannot aggregate on data that is at a lower level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below -

```
SELECT 
     inventory.inventory_id,inventory.store_id,
     rental.customer_id,customer.first_name,customer.last_name
     FROM inventory
     INNER JOIN rental ON inventory.inventory_id=rental.inventory_id
     INNER JOIN customer ON rental.customer_id=customer.customer_id
     WHERE inventory.film_id='25' and inventory.store_id in (1,2)
     group by nventory.inventory_id,inventory.store_id,
     rental.customer_id,customer.first_name,customer.last_name
     having count(distinct inventory.store_id)=2
```

Comment: I have tried this way before from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162812/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-value-in-another-column) using @Hasan Shouman 's method, however it result in a error says "aggregate function is not allowed in where...", by using your syntax although it will not result in a error but the resulted table has no values in it at all... `inventory_id | store_id | customer_id | first_name | last_name (0 rows) --------------+----------+-------------+------------+----------- `