# check if a row record exist with column record A combined with DIFFERING records from column B

Tags: sql

I have a table called `purchase contracts`

I want to select the contracts having the same supplier but different purchasers.

This is how the data looks like (C1= Contract, C2= supplier, C3= purhaser)

Dataset

[image]

I want to create a select which results in showing rows 4, 5 & 6

I've tried solution from this tread, but didn't work

[Select rows with same id but different value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162812/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-value-in-another-column)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data, and the expected result, as formatted text. I.e. no images (or links to images.)

Comment: Ok. I will keep this in mind for future posts! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.c2 = t.c2 and t1.c3 <> t.c3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.c2 = t.c2 and t2.c3 <> t.c3
             );
```