# How to select rows that have 1 column in common but another column must meet 2 conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This task has been a bit confusing for me, even to title this question was difficult. Already tried with the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162812/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-value-in-another-column) but doesn't apply in my case, because I need get something specific from COL2 ("PC" and "PP").

I need get all the rows where COL2 meet 2 conditions = 'PC' OR 'PP'. Like the example.

MY TABLE:

```
ID    COL1    COL2
1      100     PC •     
2      100     PP •     
3      100     PF 
4      200     PP   
5      200     PF    
6      300     PC •   
7      300     PP •
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
ID    COL1    COL2
1      100     PC •     
2      100     PP •      
6      300     PC •   
7      300     PP •
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but am wondering why ID Number 4 in your table is not in your desired output given its 'COL2 ' value is 'PP'. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @David Using ( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE COL2 = 'PC' OR COL2 = 'PP' ) I'm getting this row: id:4,  col1:200,  col2:PP.

Comment: @SMS Nice question. Because I dont need rows where col2 dont meet the both conditions (PC and PP)

Comment: @David Sorry maybe I haven't explained enough. Row number 4 does not meet the criteria because there is no other entry with COL1 = 200 and COL2 = PC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query:

```
select col1
from tablename
where col2 in ('PC', 'PP')
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 2
```

returns all the `col1`s that you want and you can use it with the operator `IN`:

```
select * from tablename
where col2 in ('PC', 'PP')
and col1 in (
  select col1
  from tablename
  where col2 in ('PC', 'PP')
  group by col1
  having count(distinct col2) = 2
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3bm1noVLtAVRPsxh8WSPZf/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 1   | 100  | PC   |
| 2   | 100  | PP   |
| 6   | 300  | PC   |
| 7   | 300  | PP   |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
SELECT *
FROM `table` WHERE col2 = 'pc'
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM `table` 
WHERE col2 = 'pp' AND col1 IN (SELECT col1
FROM `table` WHERE col2 = 'pc')
) a
ORDER BY a.col1 ASC, a.col2 ASC
```

Here is your Desire Result:
[image]