# Select ID with specific values in more than one field

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows

| groupCode | ProductIdentifier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dental |
| 1 | membership |
| 2 | dental |
| 2 | vision |
| 2 | health |
| 3 | dental |
| 3 | vision |

I need to find out if a specific groupCode have "dental", "vision" and "health" (all three simultaneously)

The expected result is code 2

What I need to identify is if groupCode 2 has the three products (or two, or whatever the user enters). This is part of a huge kitchen sink query I'm building.

I'm doing

```
SELECT groupCode 
FROM dbo.table
WHERE (productIdentifier = N'dental') 
  AND (productIdentifier = N'vision') 
  AND (productIdentifier = N'health') 
  AND (groupCode = 2)
```

But clearly is wrong because it's not working.

I tried to do something like its described here but it didn't return a result for me:

[Select rows with same id but different value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162812/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-value-in-another-column)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each of 'dental','vision' and 'health' occur only once per group identifier, you can group by group identifier and filter by the groups having count(*) = 3:

```
WITH
-- your input ..
indata(groupCode,ProductIdentifier) AS (
          SELECT 1,'dental'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'membership'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'dental'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'vision'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'health'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'dental'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'vision'
)
-- real query starts here ...
SELECT
  groupcode
FROM indata
WHERE productidentifier IN ('dental','vision','health')
GROUP BY
  groupcode
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
-- out  groupcode 
-- out -----------
-- out          2
```

Comment: Thanks Marco. The problem is that I dont know how many records are on the table, meaning I can do a select 1, 'membership union all select 2, ;'dental' etc... The table has about 12,000 records.

Comment: I modified my question, maybe I was not clear enough. Thanks again :)

Comment: It works with 12,000 records as it would work with the 7 records in your example. Or do you mean that you could have the combination of `group code = 1` and `product identifier = 'dental'` twice or more often?

Comment: Oh i see... Im gonna give it a try right now!

Comment: Mind you, my `WITH` clause is only there to supply data to the main query, and should not be included in the final query.

Answer (score 2):

As per Marcothesane answer, if you know the groupCode (2) and the number of products (vision, dental and health), 3 in this case, and you need to confirm if that code has those three specific products, this will work for you:

```
SELECT        COUNT(groupCode) AS totalRecords
FROM            dbo.table
WHERE       (groupCode = 2) AND (productIdentifier IN ('dental', 'vision', 'health'))
HAVING        (COUNT(groupCode) = 3)
```

This will return 3 (number of records = number of products).

Its basically's Marcothesane answer in a way you can "copy/paste" to your code by just changing the table name. You should accept Marcothesane answer.

Comment: That worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I missed (groupCode = 2) on my first answer. I just edited the code for you. Happy coding.